# push database to rooted device

Tags: android, database, insert, push

I'm trying to access the data/ folder on my device  I cant get it to open?..I've rooted my phone and I want to push my database to the database folder on my device so that I can run my developed app, it works fine on the emulator but I want to test it on a real device and its not getting the database.

I created my database with records using SQLite manager then I pushed it using DDMS on emulator. I tried inserting records using code but whenever the app starts it keeps inserting the same records is there a way to insert these record only once?

this is my insert code in DBHelper class:

```
public void inserttable1Contact(String a, String b){

                ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
                initialValues.put(KEY_a, a);
                initialValues.put(KEY_b, b);
                 db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE1, null, initialValues);}
```

and then I call it in my main class:

```
 db.inserttable1Contact("aa", "bb");
```

I've done a lot of searching but couldn't find any useful answers. 
Any help please, its very urgent.

Thanx

Comment: What's the problem, exactly? Does your app not see the data base or does it see it but insert initial data over and over?

Comment: without calling the insert method (already inserted records using sqlite manager as i asaid) ,it doesn't work I can't push it to the data folder in my device and then tried creating an empty database and calling the insert method but it keeps inserting whenever the application runs

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would override `onCreate` in your SQLiteOpenHelper to insert initial data. Since you're creating the data base by side-loading it, I suggest using some sort of persistent storage (e.g., shared prefs, or a separate, one-row table in the db) to save a flag indicating that the db has been initialized with data. Then only call `inserttable1Contact` if that flag is not set (and set the flag).

Comment: so there isn't any way to push the database I have on my PC directly to my device?

Comment: @Ama - I thought I just described one. You need to ensure that you are pushing the db file into exactly the right location. Also, the db structure needs to be exactly right (every table needs an `_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` column; if you are opening it normally, it also needs an `android_metadata` table). See, for example, [this article](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/).

Comment: the problem is that I cant access the exact location, I rooted my device but still copy it to the data/data/package/database folder and yes I have the android_metadata table and each table has an _id PK column. I tried accessing using File Expert app and I can access the location(when USB is connected only) but I cant copy the database to that location

Comment: @Ama - It sounds like there is an interaction between the local storage and the USB connection. What are your USB mass storage settings? (See ` Applications > Settings > SD Card and Phone Storage > USB connection Mode`)

Comment: I dont have USB connection mode, only external and internal sd card and their options(total space (mount,unmount) sdcard

Comment: i have my USB Debugging checked is that what you mean?

Comment: @Ama - For testing purposes, can you package the database with your app? Then at first run the app can copy it to the proper db location as described [here](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/).